# What are the default font properties of titlebar in gnome 2.28.2?

Tags: fonts, gnome, gnome2

I am trying to find the font properties in gnome 2.28.2
Is there any command or properties file where I can get all the details of font of titlebar.

Comment: This should be configured by your GTK theme, if you use system-installed one, then try `/usr/share/themes/<current-theme-name>/gtkrc`. It might also be configured by your window manager separately - you need to find out which do you use.

Comment: No, the titlebar has nothing to do with the GTK theme... The window manager in GNOME 2.x – Metacity – has a separate theme directory.